# Why the summation of normal distribution is different in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I just want to check why the result is different.

Suppose ***X*** and ***Y*** are independent standard normal distribution

***X*** ~ *N(0, 1)*

***Y*** ~ *N(0, 1)*

and the summation would be
***X*** + ***Y*** ~ *N(0, √(2) )* (according to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17800/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-sum-of-independent-normal-variables) )

So if I create the code into numpy with the shape of (1,5), it would be like this

```
np.random.seed(100)
k3 = np.random.normal(0, √(2), size=(1,5))
```

with the following result

```
k3 = array([[-0.64774797,  0.61541411, -0.82532804,  1.15519621,  0.95137089]])
```

But if I tried using the code below

```
np.random.seed(100)
k1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(1,5))
k2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(1,5))
k = k1 + k2
```

the result would be this

```
k = array([[-1.23554663,  0.56386007,  0.08299247, -0.44193187,  1.23632223]])
```

So, my question is how can **k** and **k3** be different? Does it suppose to have same result? Or did I do a misinterpretation here?

Comment: um, what is `√(2)`?

Comment: That is square root of 2 (the standard deviation of normal distribution). I don't know how to write the symbol on stackoverflow

Comment: I know what it means in *mathematics*, but that doesn't mean anything in Python. You need to provide an actual example of the code you are using to get the output you are seeing.

Comment: Why do you think these results should be the same? You are taking random samples. While it happens to be the case that the sum of two samples taken from the second distribution is identically distributed as the first distribution, why would you expect two different random sample to give you the same result?

Comment: Well I am just curious. But your answer make sense to me. One more question, do you think that k and k3 lie on the same standard deviation based on the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is equal here is the distribution of the two variables and this can be proven (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables).

To be convinced that the two distributions are the same you could look at the histograms of `k` and `k1 + k2` (note the samples come from the same distribution but are not the same!) by plotting the histograms of the arrays.

Another way to see that `k` and `k3` come from the same distribution would be to use some statistical test like t-test, spearman rank correlation, etc.

```
N = 500 # num. samples
# generate data
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(100)

k1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=N)
k2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=N)
k3 = np.random.normal(0,np.sqrt(2), size=N)

# plot data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
# side-by-side
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
sns.distplot(k1+k2)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
sns.distplot(k3)
plt.show()
# overlayed
sns.distplot(k1+k2, hist=False)
sns.distplot(k3, hist=False)
plt.show()


# test
import scipy.stats
(k1+k2).sort()
k3.sort()
#stat, p = scipy.stats.ttest_ind(k1+k2, k3)
stat, p = scipy.stats.spearmanr(k1+k2, k3)
print('Statistics=%.3f, p=%.3f' % (stat, p))
# interpret
alpha = 0.05
if p > alpha:
    print('Same distributions (fail to reject H0)')
else:
    print('Different distributions (reject H0)')

# print statistics like mean, variance
scipy.stats.describe(k3)
scipy.stats.describe(k1+k2)
```

By increasing the number of samples one sees better and better that the two distributions are the same (in your example you are just looking at 5 samples and that's too little).